# Make height equal width using differences of clientHeight/clientWidth

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, height

I set the height and width of .circle to both be 80px. However some browsers and devices set height to other values. For this example I purposely set the height and width to different values. What I'm trying to do is get the difference between clientHeight and clientWidth (in this example 80 - 50 = 30), and then subtract that from the clientHeight (80 - 30 = 50). Why doesn't this work?

PS. This function doesn't work right on any browser. Also I can't just set the height to equal clientWidth, because that isn't working on some browsers/devices either.

CSS

```
<style>
    .circle {
        height: 80px;
        width: 50px;
        border-radius: 50px;
        position: relative;
    }
    #circle1 {
        background-color: #4285F4;
    }
    #circle2 {
        background-color: #FF8F2D;
    }
    #circle3 {
        background-color: #34A853;
    }
    #circle4 {
        background-color: #EB4436;
    }
</style>
```

Javascript

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
    function circleHeight(){
        sizeDif = document.getElementById("circle1").clientHeight - document.getElementById("circle1").clientWidth;
        alert("height " + document.getElementById("circle1").clientHeight + "</br> width " +  document.getElementById("circle1").clientWidth + "</br> sizeDif " + sizeDif);

        if ((!(sizeDif = 0))) {
            $(".circle")
                .animate({
                height: document.getElementById("circle1").clientHeight - sizeDif + "px"
            }, 500);

            sizeDif = document.getElementById("circle1").clientHeight - document.getElementById("circle1").clientWidth;
            alert("height " + document.getElementById("circle1").clientHeight + "</br> width " +  document.getElementById("circle1").clientWidth + "</br> sizeDif " + sizeDif);
        }
    }
</script>
```

HTML

```
<body onload="circleHeight()">
    <p class="circle" id="circle1"></p>
    <p class="circle" id="circle2"></p>
    <p class="circle" id="circle3"></p>
    <p class="circle" id="circle4"></p>
</body>
```

Thanks

Comment: What browser set different height values? This is not supposed to happen...

Comment: Circle?...but the height and width are **set** differently...It's really not clear what the problem is or what you are trying to do.

Comment: @gioNicol This specifically happens on Safari for iPhone, when I put it on my weebly website

Comment: @Paulie_D The goal is to set the height to be 50px, which would make it a circle

Comment: If you explicitly set the height as 50px it should be fine. If it's not there is something else going on. I can't see any reason for using any other value there...if 50px  doesn't work, what makes you think 80px will? I don't this really needs a Js solution...just more investigation as to what is **actually** happening. Perhaps a link to the site might have some value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try changing this line

```
        if ((!(sizeDif = 0))) {
```

To this

```
        if (sizeDif != 0) {
```

...
But I think your code is too "polluted", try this one:

```
function circleHeight(){
    $('.circle').each(function() {
        var
        h = $(this)[0].clientHeight,
        w = $(this)[0].clientWidth,
        dif = h-w;

        if ( dif != 0 ) {
            $(this).height(h-dif);
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the missing egual sign

```
if ((!(sizeDif = 0))) {
```

Should be

```
if ((!(sizeDif == 0))) {
```